# python Popen: How do I block the execution of grep command until the content to grep is ready?

Tags: python, grep, blocking, popen

I have been fighting against Popen in python for couple of days now, so I decided to put all my doubts here, hopefully all of them can be clarified by python experts.

Initially I use Popen to execute a command and grep the result(as one command using pipe, something like `xxx | grep yyy`), with `shell=False`, as you can imagine, that doesn't work quite well. Following the guide in [this](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t725178-how-do-subprocess-popen-ls-grep-foo-shell-true-withshell-false.html) post, I changed my code to the following:

```
checkCmd = ["sudo", "pyrit", "-r", self.capFile, "analyze"]
checkExec = Popen(checkCmd, shell=False, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
grepExec = Popen(["grep", "good"], stdin=checkExec.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
output = grepExec.stdout.readline()
output = grepExec.communicate()[0]
```

But I realized that the `checkExec` runs slowly and since Popen is non-blocking, `grepExec` always get executed before `checkExec` shows any result, thus the grep output would always be blank. How can I postpone the execution of `grepExec` till `checkExec` is finished?

1. In another Popen in my program, I tried to keep a service open at the back, so I use a separate thread to execute it. When all the tasks are done, I notify this thread to quit, and I explicitly call Popen.kill() to stop the service. However, my system ends up with a zombie process that is not reaped. I don't know if there's a nice way to clean up everything in this background thread after it finishes?
2. What are the differences between Popen.communicate()[0] and Popen.stdout.readline()? Can I use a loop to keep reading output from both of them?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you do not want to use the shell's pipe functionality? (with `|`)

Comment: @mensi: I specified shell=False, so pipe might not be working. I tried the pipe in shell=False at the beginning, but Popen only executes the command without grep after the pipe.

Comment: @mensi there are lots of good reasons to not have your `Popen` spawn a subshell -- doing a direct `execv()` syscall from your script means you don't need to take care to quote your arguments to be parsed by the shell in the way you expect, which can be a Very Big Deal from a security perspective if they contain user-generated data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example would work if you do it like this:

```
checkCmd = ["sudo", "pyrit", "-r", self.capFile, "analyze"]
checkExec = Popen(checkCmd, shell=False, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
grepExec = Popen(["grep", "good"], stdin=checkExec.stdout, stdout=PIPE)

for line in grepExec.stdout:
    # do something with line
```

You use communicate when you want to give some input to a process and read all output on stdout, stderr of the process at the same time. This is probably not what you want for your case. `communicate` is more for the cases where you want to start an application, feed all the input it needs to it and read its output.

As other answers have pointed out you can use `shell=True` to create the pipeline in your call to subprocess, but an alternative which I would prefer is to leverage python and instead of setting up a pipeline doing:

```
checkCmd = ["sudo", "pyrit", "-r", self.capFile, "analyze"]
checkExec = Popen(checkCmd, shell=False, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
for line in checkExec.stdout:
    if line.find('good') != -1:
        do something with the matched line here
```

Answer (score 2):

Use subprocess instead of popen, then you can simplify things drastically with the complete commandline.

http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

eg.

```
import subprocess as sub
f = open('/dev/null', 'w')
proc = sub.call("cat file | grep string", executable="/bin/bash", shell=True)
```

Comment: This approach may be easier on the simple case, but is harder to get right when assembling the command line from user inputs -- if the string being grepped for is user-generated, for instance, than it needs to be quoted in this case... but _not_ when using `Popen` with an array and no `shell=True`.

Comment: I guess in this case there's no way that I can store the output in my program, right?

Comment: @da_zhuang with that particular syntax, yes, I just pulled one from a script I'm using. You'd want to use the `subprocess.check_output` method. And assembling the command line from user input is trivial using the usual methods, formatted print strings in variable assignment, variable substitution, etc. 

I didn't delve into your specific case details because the docs page has all the info and example you need.